# Vega-Lite Calculated Scale domainMax

Tags: vega-lite, yaxis

I'm trying to calculate a value for domainMax on the Y-axis scale. I tried the following example where I want the Y-axis domainMax to be one greater than the maximum value in the dataset field named "value". The example produces the error 'Unrecognized signal name: "domMax"'. How can I get it to work?

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00", "value": 1},
      {"date": "2021-04-01T00:00:00", "value": 3},
      {"date": "2021-05-01T00:00:00", "value": 2}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    { "calculate": "max(datum.value)+1","as": "domMax"}
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domainMax": {"expr": "domMax"}}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to get a custom domain based on the data but hit the same limitations as you did.

In my case, I update the data from the outside a bit like [the streaming example](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/streaming.html). I compute the domain from the outside and modify them in the visualization with params. This is quite easy as vega-lite params are exposed as vega signals.

This is the gist of the layout:

```json
  {
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "params": [
      {
        "name": "lowBound",
        "value": -10
      },
      {
        "name": "highBound",
        "value": 100
      }
    ],
    ../..
    "vconcat": [
      {
        "name": "detailed",
        ../..
        "layer": [
          { 
            ../..
            "mark": "line",
            "encoding": {
              "y": {
                "field": "value",
                "title": "Temperature",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "scale": {
                  "domainMin": {
                    "expr": "lowBound"
                  },
                  "domainMax": {
                    "expr": "highBound"
                  }
                }
              },
...
```

The `lowBound` and `highBound` are dynamically changed through vega signals. I change them with the regular JS API.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I still have not solved my problem but this suggestion was helpful in pointing me to using a range input parameter.  I'm using the Power BI Deneb control and have a multi-layer chart, which I think is an issue when placing the parameter  outside of the layer array. When I place the parameter within a layer, the chart fails to render. Also, I have not found a way to pass in a computed value from outside the Deneb control because of the original issue of requiring a signal versus a dataset column. Still trying...

Comment: I don't know anything about Power BI so I can't help on that part. But if it helps, I also have a multi-layer graph and it seems to work. I'll edit my answer to show the structure I use.

Answer (score 3):

1. This transform

   ```
   "transform": [
       { "calculate": "max(datum.value)+1","as": "domMax"}
    ]
   ```

   adds a new column to your data set - it does not create a new signal. You can check that [in the editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoVZjhoQAJgAMlgIz9rAZkd2AKteupP364pDauuaodgC+CiZqwVa2DtYALK4eXj6e-oF6aE7hkWYWNvaOYkmpKX5KGcGWoQC64SCYAE5IshAAZmyNCEagUDpQDIJRFsgAHgAUpgwIlJUAlADUdv5IBujKbAgAskijILVKyI0A1hbCsuZKcLJQbMo0smRooHuaIG00cILKFqaXDQBPHDRMwIHCdHT7JQA57vT7fCyVfyYIHRACODBamDoahopH2oVCQA). Go to the **DataViewer** tab and select **data_0** from the drop down. Can you see the new **domMax** column?

2. Signals are a different thing entirely - have a look [here](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/signals/) in the documentation.  Note that the link points to Vega, not Vega-Lite. (Vega-Lite specifications are compiled to Vega.)
3. Vega-Lite does not let you declare signals; you declare parameters instead. Here is [another example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQOJACckCCGgDaoWRrhoQAEzYIAskgAeikMSSCGh1ABYAvgF0lxpJhSpQe0c4LVRdE19nEAAmAAZogEZ+WIBmZISAFVjY1Gzc2NsgpzQEtwVQH0wouMTkl3SsnLzswodi1BSyisijGqTYsQbmpoKlIudozzKQTHVZCAAzNlUEHVAoBygGQR70ZCsACkqGBEpxgEoAagTbJFCTM0sbTyVkVQBrI2FZQyU4WSgbGMNFkZDQoBsARACxocEExiMlV+MwAnjgolUEDhlg4QNMUeDobD4UZxrZMGiogBHBhIWSYOi+GikWzQBzOCpmJAgp6EuBWHCqRGPax4tzitxAA) using the `domMax` parameter. Vega-Lite parameters are translated to Vega signals.
4. It looks like you are trying to derive the value of your parameter/signal from the data. I am not sure you can do that in Vega-Lite.
5. On the other hand it's very easy in Vega. For example you could use the extent transform:
   https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/extent/

Side comment - while Vega specifications are more verbose you can sometimes find their primitives simpler and a good way to understand how the visualisation works. (You can see compiled Vega in the editor.)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation and examples. Even though it doesn't solve the problem, it is very useful information, I learned a lot and will avoid wasting time on the path I was on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a param to [pan and zoom](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bind.html#scale-binding) in case your hard coded values are less than ideal.

`"params": [{"name": "grid", "select": "interval", "bind": "scales"}],`

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUkUG8IATAAykCMAtOQMx1UAq55cbH5IANCMumJwArAF8eBaELKVa5ACxNW7Tm179UmeKXGSiJCtTrClqldz4CtceqIC64kAAcIAJwgBbHHHwgAdp7SAOauAJZg6lgYKBgAxlAkoX5ErgLqAEZJEXAgWLGo2CD2fB5uANYkKEnEfBh+sQD2YElB8KAAHm0gAGah0dngUupQAJ5O0kQeTg3uKEV8I129-SRWNSCj4yQAjmgQyaEwUKGI63kFXWANpUl45DzyDqLPQA)