# Dynamic maximum value for a shared Y-axis with multiple layers in Vega Lite

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega

I'm working on a Vega Lite scatter plot with multiple layers, and I'm encountering a problem when trying to set the maximum value for a shared Y-axis dynamically.

My dataset already has a dynamically calculated field, MAX_ARP, and I want to use its maximum value as the maximum value for the Y-axis in each layer. Each layer has a transform with a calculate operation to offset the positions of the points on the X-axis, as shown below:

```
"transform": [{"calculate": "-35", "as": "axis"}],
"transform": [{"calculate": "-70", "as": "axis"}],
"transform": [{"calculate": "-70", "as": "axis"}]
```

It seems that the fact that I am offsetting the positions of points on the X-axis affects some of the solutions I tried to set the Y-axis. Everything was off, and the scatter plot didn't make any sense.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6BRM.png

I tried using the following method to get the global maximum value of MAX_ARP and then set it as the domainMax for the Y-axis:

```
"transform": [
  {
    "window": [
      {
        "op": "max",
        "field": "MAX_ARP",
        "as": "max_arp_value"
      }
    ],
    "frame": [null, null]
  }
]

...

"domainMax": {"field": "max_arp_value"}
```

However, when I try this approach, it returns an error:

```
Unsupported object: {"field":"max_arp_value"}.
```

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions on how to set the dynamic maximum value for a shared Y-axis with multiple layers in my Vega Lite scatter plot, using the MAX_ARP field from my dataset.

In the encoding section of each Layer, I'm currently using

```
    "scale": {
                      "domainMin": 0,
                      "domainMax": 400
                      }
```

, but it nos a viable option as the maximum value will change depending on the dataset !

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using a filter on your dataset like this?
Here I get the MAX(MAX_ARP) = 250 and then filter y & x <= 250

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 100, "y": 100, "MAX_ARP": 100},
      {"x": 200, "y": 200, "MAX_ARP": 200},
      {"x": 300, "y": 300, "MAX_ARP": 250},
      {"x": 400, "y": 400, "MAX_ARP": 100}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
     {
    "window": [
      {
        "op": "max",
        "field": "MAX_ARP",
        "as": "max_arp_value"
      }
    ],
    "frame": [null, null]
  },
    {"filter": "datum.x <= datum.max_arp_value && datum.y <= datum.max_arp_value"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Adam (APB Reports)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example. So now we set the domainMax dynamically and also allow the user to scroll in/out to see all the data.

Based on answers here:

[How To Set Dynamic Max Domain in VegaLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76281372/how-to-set-dynamic-max-domain-in-vegalite)

[Vega-Lite Calculated Scale domainMax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71028396/vega-lite-calculated-scale-domainmax)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 100, "y": 100, "MAX_ARP": 100},
      {"x": 200, "y": 200, "MAX_ARP": 250},
      {"x": 300, "y": 300, "MAX_ARP": 200},
      {"x": 400, "y": 400, "MAX_ARP": 200}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "max", "field": "MAX_ARP", "as": "max"}]}
  ],
  "params": [
    {"name": "highBound", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['max']"},
    {"name": "grid", "select": "interval", "bind": "scales"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "x",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"domainMax": {"expr": "highBound"}}
        },
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```