# How To Set Dynamic Max Domain in VegaLite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have a vega-lite plot that streams data, and I want the `domainMax` for x-axis to always be one value higher than the extent of the data.

I'm using `ExprRef` to specify what I want

```
"encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "time",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "domainMax": {
          "expr": "extent(datum.time)[1] + 1"
        }
      },
   }
}
```

But I get the following error in Vega Editor Logs

`[Error] datum is not defined`

The full spec can be found here: [Open in Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgBMABh1L4NMlm16lauNABONHJnbz0AUWJtBDe3IAEbAGZeII2QAfQAPLyRZNQCgpGCAT0UQNSRMFFRQWSQEODQQCFDgiESlYiR3SzQAbVB7HLQAdgAWSjEmgE5Orq6G9oBGJUCyENCFIZDE1H4dSgA2JoAODoBmBoWxWdmFha0msSVMeJxc9EBh4FCQAF8FWpp61GbWju7u3oH82LCxz8mZ5rE+gsdFotDsxOsxFp2gcjicQKdEtdbvdHmIXi9eoNPqNxnFJtM5usGpDeg0dAs+sSQTDjnlzlcbiA6idUejXtCPsM4jifmg-n1ye0tOCljomk1ZmJljS4QirgBda4gZBWADWaFqsLywlkuSUUGEODQmCsDDgSrgsigbDUNFkZA1IAuGRAvhocEEajyzKSh1p6AAjgxIvY0vZSEloOUTqA1GxkHaALJIZ2gOChHBWPLpzCWzAAChSmAYCEozIAlFU+vKvABqLx9K5KlM0CCOwRIJgegBickwAGUaAAvE66A50QRwXuyAfD0f7JkTuHMrz5iBwa1RCDlptKSagN0er3oXFfU8lJlawPBmd0VI0CODKDRx1xhOOKr8AbV5uhVvtzsez7QcR1McdMEnadZ1A1BhXAyc6VGLw5UuJVrUENgsxdQ9PW9LUZTyWR4ztcokknMhLWPUAOy7QQoJA0d9EXCC4SbVCgA)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can refer to a datum there. Try this:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "description": "Evolution of sigma_x and sigma_y",
  "data": {
    "name": "sx_sy",
    "values": [
      {
        "time": 74.54999999999791,
        "sigma_x,sigma_y": -0.6484937856688245,
        "type": "σx"
      },
      {
        "time": 74.54999999999791,
        "sigma_x,sigma_y": 0.7451802282585529,
        "type": "σy"
      },
      {
        "time": 74.5999999999979,
        "sigma_x,sigma_y": -0.6857527970817522,
        "type": "σx"
      },
      {
        "time": 74.5999999999979,
        "sigma_x,sigma_y": 0.7108925884044653,
        "type": "σy"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "max", "field": "time", "as": "max"}]}
  ],
  "params": [{"name": "max", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['max']"}],
  "mark": {"type": "line", "clip": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "time",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domainMax": {"expr": "max+0.1"}},
      "axis": {
        "labelFontSize": 20,
        "titleFontSize": 25,
        "title": "time (seconds)"
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "sigma_x,sigma_y",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": [-1, 1]},
      "axis": {"labelFontSize": 20, "titleFontSize": 25, "title": "σx, σy"}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "type",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": {"labelFontSize": 20, "title": ""}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. For anyone that's looking to do this in a layered plot with different data sources, I had to declare the `params` outside the `layer` attribute, while the transform within the relevant `data` attribute (inside the `layer`).